# JQuery Name+Variable as an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating some new HTML in Jquery like this:

```
$('<div class="child" id='cross' + counter + '></div>')
```

`counter` is a variable and `cross` is a Text.

`id` should be something like `cross1` `cross2` etc, depending on the value stored in counter.

How can I fix this up?

Comment: How are you producing these new elements? Where are you having problems **specifically**, other than syntax errors?

Comment: you have used the wrong quote to open your id - `$('<div class="child" id="cross' + counter + '"></div>')`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/mw9xorb3/6/ May helps you

Comment: Classic quotes problem.

Comment: @downvoter this question is clearly and well formatted and is within topic.... so elaborate pls

Comment: @closecasters This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center. ?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create element using jQuery and use its method to set your data.

```
$('<div></div>')
    .prop('id', "cross" + counter)
    .html(YourHTMLTextIfAny);
```

Apart from that, fix quotes

```
$('<div class="child" id="cross' + counter + '"></div>')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be because of improperly formatted code. The quotes are a little mixed up.

```
$("<div class='child' id='cross" + counter + "'></div>")
```

This should work. To insert it into the DOM, you could do something like:

```
$('body').append("<div class='child' id='cross" + counter + "'></div>")
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/1ok6b2ro/).

Answer (score 0):

`$('<div class="child" id="cross' + counter + '"></div>')`

There is double quote issue with your code. Above is the correct one. Put this is any loop and increment the counter only so that you can get what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div class="child" id="cross' + counter + '"></div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to append that div to an DOM element (body i.e.) just do

```
var html = ('<div class="child" id="cross' + counter + '"></div>';

$(body).append(html);
```

and further insert some text:

```
$("#cross" + counter).html("hello world");
```